# Changing datetime format which includes weekday?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, timestamp

Currently I have datetime column in this format

```
        Datime
        Thu Jun 18 23:04:19 +0000 2020
        Thu Jun 18 23:04:18 +0000 2020
        Thu Jun 18 23:04:14 +0000 2020
        Thu Jun 18 23:04:13 +0000 2020
```

I want to change it to:

```
   Datetime
 2020-06-18 23:04:19
 2020-06-18 23:04:18
 2020-06-18 23:04:14
 2020-06-18 23:04:13
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have loaded your pandas dataframe, you can convert `Datetime` column to specified format using this function. You can rename this function.

```
import datetime

def modify_datetime(dtime):
    my_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(dtime, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y')
    return my_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

First argument to `strptime` function is date string and second argument is format.

```
Directive, Description

%a         Weekday abbreviated
%b         Month abbreviated name
%d         Day of the month
%H         Hour (24-hour format)
%M         Minute with zero padding
%S         Second with zero padding
%z         UTC offset
%Y         Full year
```

Once you converted string date to `datetime` objects you can convert it back to string with specified format using `strftime` function. You can read more about formats [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

Finally, just modify the `Datetime` column

```
df['Datetime'] = df['Datetime'].apply(modify_datetime)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`pandas.Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) appropriately:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime_strs = ["Thu Jun 18 23:04:19 +0000 2020", "Thu Jun 18 23:04:18 +0000 2020", "Thu Jun 18 23:04:14 +0000 2020", "Thu Jun 18 23:04:13 +0000 2020"]
>>> d = {'Datetimes': datetime_strs}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>> df
                        Datetimes
0  Thu Jun 18 23:04:19 +0000 2020
1  Thu Jun 18 23:04:18 +0000 2020
2  Thu Jun 18 23:04:14 +0000 2020
3  Thu Jun 18 23:04:13 +0000 2020
>>> df['Datetimes'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetimes'], format='%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y')
>>> df
                  Datetimes
0 2020-06-18 23:04:19+00:00
1 2020-06-18 23:04:18+00:00
2 2020-06-18 23:04:14+00:00
3 2020-06-18 23:04:13+00:00
>>> df['Datetimes'] = df['Datetimes'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> df
             Datetimes
0  2020-06-18 23:04:19
1  2020-06-18 23:04:18
2  2020-06-18 23:04:14
3  2020-06-18 23:04:13
```